# Why python netaddr copies variable references instead of creating a new instance

Tags: python, inetaddress

I want to make a copy of an IPNetwork variable not reference (and change) the existing one.  Why does changing 'x' below also change 'nw'?

```
>>> nw=IPNetwork('1.1.1.1/24')
>>> nw
IPNetwork('1.1.1.1/24')
>>> x = nw
>>> x.prefixlen = 28
>>> nw
IPNetwork('1.1.1.1/28')
```

Comment: Assignment in Python means something completely different from what you're thinking. Read up: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Thanks. That does help. So in my case "nw' is a pointer to an instance of the IPNetwork class. When I assign x to IPNetwork(nw) I made a new instance with initial values that are the same as nw but stored and operated on separately.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the variable assignment. `x = nw` is telling the variable `x` to point to the same object that `nw` is pointing to.

What you need is a list or other mutable object:

```
>>> nw = [IPNetwork('1.1.1.1/24')]
>>> x = nw
>>> x[0].prefixlen = 28
>>> x[0]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately this is complex and has the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this has the same result of x and nw referring to the same variable:
        from netaddr import *
        nw = [IPNetwork('1.1.1.1/24')] 
        x = nw
        x[0].prefixlen=28
        x
    [IPNetwork('1.1.1.1/28')]
        nw
    [IPNetwork('1.1.1.1/28')]

I came up with the solution of using IPNetwork to create a new instance:
        nw=IPNetwork('1.1.1.1/24')
        nw
    IPNetwork('1.1.1.1/24')
        x = IPNetwork(nw)
        x.prefixlen=28
        x
    IPNetwork('1.1.1.1/28')
        nw
    IPNetwork('1.1.1.1/24')